# Ho do I get my website tools used by other websites

Tags: seo, widgets

I hope someone can help me. I'm new to SEO and as of now have just about no budget. I'm trying to get more traffic to my site. Someone suggested that I use the tools on my site, shown in the links below, to generate traffic.

I wondered how I go about this? What sites could I target and how I would approach this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

www.debt-out.co.uk/budget-calculator

www.debt-out.co.uk/debt-test

Answer (score 2):

SEO is a constant effort that the webmaster has to do in order to increase PR (Page Rank) in search engines (like Google, Yahoo, Bing!, etc.).

For a general answer, refer to [this topic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/2/4803).

For a specific answer, you'll need to use [Google Adwords](http://adwords.google.com/) in order to advertise your product on targeted websites. There are a plethora of third-party tools that will assist in getting what you made visible. **SEO isn't an immediate process**, these things take time.

In the general answer, you'll find links and references to other tools to help you get some better traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Totally in agreement with Christopher. You may also find this useful:

http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

Also:

http://www.seomoz.org/blog/learn-seo-in-30-minutes-a-day

Good luck =)